# sql INSERT successful/not successful messages don't display properly

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using a form to insert records into my database.  The error checking works and the records insert correctly.  The problem is the record insert message displays above the form instead of underneath it.  I've tried moving the INSERT query so it dislays under the form but when I do, the error checking doesn't work.  Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <p class="first"><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <br>

<?php
function test_input($data){
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "oldga740_Tonymm";
$password = "JtAjDm#6";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";

// create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !$connection->connect_error){
    // to track errors
    $error = false;

    // now validate input fields
    if (empty($_POST['Project']) || !isset($_POST['Project'])){
        $ProjectErr = "Project name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$/",$_POST['Project'])){
        // check if project only contains number, letters, comma's periods and whitespace
        $ProjectErr = "Only letters, numbers, comma's, periods and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $Project = test_input($_POST['Project']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['Client']) || !isset($_POST['Client'])){
        $ClientErr = "Client name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z 0-9.-]+$/",$_POST['Client'])){
        // check if project only contains number, letters, comma's periods and whitespace
        $ClientErr = "Only letters, numbers, comma's, periods and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $Client = test_input($_POST['Client']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['LastName']) || !isset($_POST['LastName'])){
        $LastNameErr = "Last name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/",$_POST['LastName'])){
        // check if last name only contains letters and whitespace
        $LastNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $LastName = test_input($_POST['LastName']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['DateReceived']) || !isset($_POST['DateReceived'])){
        $DateReceivedErr = "Date received is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/",$_POST['DateReceived'])){
        // check if data received only contains letters and whitespace
        $DateReceivedErr = "Date must be entered as YYYY/MM/DD";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $DateReceived = test_input($_POST['DateReceived']);
    }

    if(!$error){
        $query = "INSERT INTO Projects (Project, Client, LastName, DateReceived) VALUES ('$Project', '$Client', '$LastName', '$DateReceived')";
        if($connection->query($query)){
            echo "record is successfully inserted!";
        }else{
            echo "error: record could not be inserted";
        }
    }
}

?>

<?php
    $connection->close();
?>
<form action="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/NewProject.php" method="post">

<div class="fieldset">
        <fieldset>

        Project: <input type="text" name="Project" value="<?php if(isset($Project)){ echo $Project; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ProjectErr)){ echo $ProjectErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        Client: <input type="text" name="Client" value="<?php if(isset($Client)){ echo $Client; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ClientErr)){ echo $ClientErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php if(isset($LastName)){ echo $LastName; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($LastNameErr)){ echo $LastNameErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        DateReceived: <input type="text" name="DateReceived" value="<?php if(isset($DateReceived)){ echo $DateReceived; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($DateReceivedErr)){ echo $DateReceivedErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
     </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable a store the message and then display it wherever you need, like this:

```
// your code

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !$connection->connect_error){
    // your code

    if(!$error){
        $query = "INSERT INTO Projects (Project, Client, LastName, DateReceived) VALUES ('$Project', '$Client', '$LastName', '$DateReceived')";
        if($connection->query($query)){
            $message = "record is successfully inserted!";
        }else{
            $message = "error: record could not be inserted";
        }
    }
}

?>

<?php
    $connection->close();
?>
<form action="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/NewProject.php" method="post">

    <div class="fieldset">
        <fieldset>
            Project: <input type="text" name="Project" value="<?php if(isset($Project)){ echo $Project; } ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ProjectErr)){ echo $ProjectErr; } ?></span>
            <br><br>
            Client: <input type="text" name="Client" value="<?php if(isset($Client)){ echo $Client; } ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ClientErr)){ echo $ClientErr; } ?></span>
            <br><br>
            LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php if(isset($LastName)){ echo $LastName; } ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($LastNameErr)){ echo $LastNameErr; } ?></span>
            <br><br>
            DateReceived: <input type="text" name="DateReceived" value="<?php if(isset($DateReceived)){ echo $DateReceived; } ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($DateReceivedErr)){ echo $DateReceivedErr; } ?></span>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>

    <?php

        if(isset($message)){ echo $message; }

    ?>

// your code
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  I never thought to assign result as a different variable.  I need to start thinking outside the box.